# Double width 2D content when using the (proprietary) nvidia driver with Intel graphics in dual monitor setup

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, proprietary-drivers

I've been going around this for ages and can't seem to get it working under Ubuntu.

I have a Dell Latitude E6420 with integrated Intel/Nvidia graphics. I can use each monitor independently or connect two monitors (via dock) to the Nvidia chip. But whenever I want to use Nvidia + Intel together (either in 1+1 or 2+1 combination) I get the weird artifact as shown below.

The 3D-accelerated part of the desktop (the Unity shell) shows up properly but everything else is double-stretched. Only the display itself is stretched, if I want to click the button with a mouse I need to click on the original position where the button would be.

This has been happening since 14.04 onward.

[image: Dual monitor setup]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant information:

```
lspci

....
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
....
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
....


aptitude search nvidia | grep ^i

iB  nvidia-346                      - NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.59     
i A nvidia-opencl-icd-346           - NVIDIA OpenCL ICD                         
i   nvidia-prime                    - Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime            
i A nvidia-settings                 - Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics d

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem have something to do with this feature [Add Window Contents scaling options to Display panel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1297053).

Some more info here: [BrightnessAndDisplays](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BrightnessAndDisplays#Scaling)

Probably a bug or just a misconfiguration, I'm not a Ubuntu user and there's not such feature on Debian, this question would probably fit better on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), the feature looks to me like an Ubuntu customization unique to Ubuntu (not available on other distros).

I would try contact some support for Ubuntu users (mailing list? forum?) or the maintainers of the package `unity-control-center` (I don't know if Ubuntu have something like Debian's bugreport, wild guess.. yes, but before filling a bug you should try to understand if is really a bug or just a misconfiguration)

Comment: I'll check if this helps in any way, thanks. The funny thing is that this happens 9 out of 10 times (so sometimes it does work). The windows are scaled only horizontally though.

Comment: Quick update: reading through the docs of "Brightness And Displays" I am pessimistic it would help, as this settings are per display and I get artefacts across all displays. Will come back with results.

Comment: @boky give it a try, I remember when I used two monitor in some configuration they were *seen* as a unique big *window* (even if they didn't match in height! the smallest had a higher virtual size with pan enabled)

Comment: @boky *This has been happening since 14.04 onward* which is when the feature has been introduced, also, did you try other distros? Any other with the same problem? I dont't think this is an hardware problem because the unity shell is fine, and the fact that the feature make distinction between menu and window content is more suspect to me..

Comment: Will try and post back results. Did not try other distros but even clean install did not fix the issue. Funny thing is that the login screen works properly though -- I suspect that because it's completely accelerated and/or created in the same way as unity.

Comment: Again I'm not Ubuntu expert and don't know if this would work on it but, you could try go into a runlevel without X and start X manually, then play around with randr arandr to configure the two monitor and check if they stretch

Comment: Thanks. Checked. Doesn't seem to be it. Although the latest NVIDIA drivers (346-updates) seem to have fixed the issue a bit.